# Apache Server CORS and self signed certificate issues

Tags: apache, ssl, cross-domain, cors

I have an Apache server that I'm attempting to send requests over HTTPS to, but I've been struggling to get past cross origin issues as well as issues using SSL.

I'm not exactly sure where the problem lies, as I seem to be getting different responses back from the web consoles (testing with Firefox + Chrome) concerning the failed request.  In Chrome, I simply see that the request that is sent as a POST is changed to OPTIONS and notes that it failed without much else.  In Firefox, I see the following two issues:

In the console, the request says it fails due to CORS:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://123.456.789.001. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

However, inspecting the failed request in the network tab shows the following issue about the certificate:

> 123.456.789.001 uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

After digging, I'm having issues determining what is actually causing the request to fail - is it because my CORS rules are not setup properly?  Or is it because I'm attempting to send requests to a server that is using a self signed certificate and therefore not being trusted by my request/browser?

I believe CORS is setup properly on my end, here are the contents of the files I'm using to enable CORS:

Crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

.htaccess:

```
# Always set these headers.
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, X-Frame-Options"

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Obviously these settings aren't great for production, but after spending hours trying to pinpoint the issue, I went with some examples that were the least restrictive in terms of enabling CORS hoping I'd see the requests go through and then go back and edit them properly.  However, I still see the Cross Origin errors in the console with these changes uploaded to the Apache server (and server restarted after files changed).

So is there anyway to tell if CORS or the self-signed certificate is causing the issue?  I didn't necessarily want to go ahead and purchase a SSL certificate at this time since I'm still in development, and the site I'm using to host the content is forced to https, so I can't pass the requests over http.

Comment: For local testing I would suggest using your host file to associate the IP with a fake domain name, reissuing the cert on that domain, installing it into the trusted cert store and retesting

Comment: Thats true. I was hoping to allow small group of testers to access the page as well, and didn't want to have to force them to accept and install certificates on their local machines if at all possible.

Comment: Well you can pickup a legit SSL cert for ~$7

Comment: Ah, I've had no luck finding them for that cheap - which site/provider are you using to get them for ~$7?  I was a bit apprehensive to go buy an SSL cert to test this issue in case it wasn't the cert causing the failed requests, but I'd be more than willing to pick one up cheaply to test with.

Comment: I've use cheap ones from https://www.ssls.com/ without probs although for production just to be safe I use the 99.9% coverage ones

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely give them a try and see if my requests are still failing after the valid ssl certs are in place.

Comment: I'm using JQuery which seems to be making a point of avoiding the OPTIONS preflight check. Without that check, my CORS call errors because the call to the untrusted server is "insecure". So it's likely something you'll have to deal with even if your OPTIONS call is failing for another reason. (Cheap workaround: navigate the browser to a URL on the untrusted server-- Chrome/Firefox asks if you want to trust it. Do so, then navigate the same browser window back to your page.)